# Constant failure in bandpass filter simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, pspice, band-pass

some of you probably remember my last question, but I like to reiterate: I created a bandpass filter with the help of the online tool *FilterWizard*, which should block below 30 kHz and above 300 kHz; the whole thing with ± 9V supply voltage and 3dB gain in the pass band. In addition, it has been optimized in the direction of *Low Noise*.

Under the ‘Voltage Range’ tab on the website, it is stated that the signal may range from -8.25V to 8.75V.

As you can see in the schematic created by the online tool, there is an **AD8022**. Since I use *PSpice for TI 2021.1*, I “only” have the components from *Texas Instruments*. I searched back and forth for a long time until I found a (apparently) suitable operational amplifier. I entered the specifications of the AD8022 (slew rate, gain bandwidth, Voltage Offset, Voltage Noise) on the Texas Instruments website and found and installed the **THS4021**. I've also tried others before.
The problem is that no matter how good the op amps are on paper, the simulation always results in nonsense. I have already cross-checked whether I made a mistake in the schematic. **What's going on?**

This project is for training purposes only – I am not a qualified electrical engineer.
Unfortunately I cannot offer you an *.asc file*.

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Analog Filter Wizard – planned Magnitude

[image: Analog Filter Wizard – planned Magnitude]

Analog Filter Wizard – given circuit

[image: Analog Filter Wizard – given circuit]

Analog Filter Wizard – Voltage Range tab

[image: Analog Filter Wizard – Voltage Range tab]

my circuit (jointed image)

[image: my circuit (jointed)]

**Simulation:** red curve: Voltage Source; green curve: VOut

[image: Simulation]

https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8022.html#product-overview

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4021.pdf?ts=1635693680345

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**Edit:** Attached is a picture with graphs of what components R3, R5 and C7 see at their input.

[image: R3 R5 C7]

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**Edit 2:** While everything is ok on the left side of the C7, ‘Node N02220’ (orange line) sees this… .

[image: sub-image of the circuit]

[image: what the node sees]

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**Edit 3:** I have now reduced the voltage to a tenth. This seems to work to me, except that from around 250kHz the amplitude of VOut is no longer as large as it should be up to 300kHz.

[image]

Comment: perhaps the negative rail psu v3  is wrong polarity?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič With the THS4021 it has to be like this, says the data sheet.

Comment: I have got the impression that your supply voltages are not correct. Please check.

Comment: Investigate each stage's output waveform from L to R until you find the one that's clipping.

Comment: I've edit the question.

Comment: I see no "clipping" - instead I see a kind of superimposed oscillations.

Comment: Why are you using such a large input voltage for TRAN simulation?

Comment: **+1** for annotating DC biasing voltages in the schematic ! 1) Try reducing the amplitude at the input, how does 85 mV (100x less than you have now) work? 2) Those THS4021 opamps are **bloody fast**, hmm, are they unity gain stable? Let's look in the datasheet: Hmm: "Stable at a Gain of 10 (–9) or Greater" I think that's your problem!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ok thanks. Um, what do you want me to do?

Comment: The AD8022's datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8022.pdf does not mention unity gain stability but the internal schematic (fig. 38) does show a frequency compensation capacitor so I'm guessing that the AD8022 **is** unity gain stable. The schematic of the THS4021 (fig 30 in https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4022.pdf ) does **not** show such a capacitor so...

Comment: *Um, what do you want me to do?* Whatever makes you happy! I would choose a slower opamp, one that does **not** state "Stable at a Gain of x(–x) or Greater" or one that shows "unity gain stable". Other clues: in the internal schematic there's a freq. comp. cap like the AD8022 has. In the datasheet there are example schematics where the opamp is used in unity gain (- input directly connected to output, like you have).

Comment: I don't think you need such a high GBW product. My guess is that Analog Devices suggests the AD8022 because they sell it and it should always be fast enough. But you're not making much gain and your BW is also limited at 300 kHz so a GBW of 10 MHz might suffice. I would try the NE5532 which is a well known opamp so it should have a model. Just ignore slewrate and noise (although NE5532 is "low noise") for the moment.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I didn't know about "unity gain stable". Thanks for that. I have now reduced the voltage to a tenth. This seems to work to me, except that from around 250kHz the amplitude of VOut is no longer as large as it should be up to 300kHz. I'll upload photos again in a moment.

Comment: Another pro-tip: if you really see the influence op the opamp, make a circuit with **ideal opamps**! Simply replace the opamps with VCVS (Voltage Controlled Voltage Source) with a gain of 1000. Then you can simulate the "ideal" transfer function and compare that to what happens when using a real opamp's model.

Comment: *I have now reduced the voltage to a tenth.* Also note how that last plot doesn't show a "smooth" sinewave, that means you need **more simulation points**. For a simulation like this you might want to set the maximum timestep such that you get at least 10000 points. But all this doesn't solve the main issue that the THS4021 are simply too fast. Replace them with the NE5532 and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have the NE5532 in my library.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am now using the THS4031 (120 MHz GBW). The result is satisfactory, except that, as before, at 250kHz and above it is quite attenuated. Where it should still be 1:1. By the way: Do I understand you correctly: operational amplifiers can be too fast?

Comment: *operational amplifiers can be too fast?* Yes, in your case the THS4021 is "too fast". This opamp doesn't have internal frequency compensation to make it fast. Frequency compensation places a pole in the opamp's transfer function so that that pole will be the dominant pole when using that opamp in unity gain. Many fast opamps do not have that pole so that they're as fast as possible. But then the circuit around the opamp needs to take care that the circuit is stable. That is not possible in a unity gain circuit.

Comment: @Daniel Do you need 8th order fall-off with 3db gain? I figure I'd better ask that, just to make sure those are hard specs.

Comment: @jonk _Do you need 8th order fall-off with 3db gain? I figure I'd better ask that, just to make sure those are hard specs_ Well, it's a practice project. Admittedly, 8th order also seems heavy to me.  

Comment: But I wanted to do a little more than "standard low-pass filter"

Comment: @Daniel Well, I once had to design (I never wanted to do it another time) a 10-pole receive filter and a 6-pole transmit filter for a 600 bps FSK modem for the old copper ground phone lines that used to exist more than they do now. I needed that level of performance. So I have an idea of just how difficult it is to create a good quality 8-pole filter from discretes. And that's partly why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary for future readers:**
After learning the word "Unity Gain" in the sense of operational amplifiers, I looked for such opamps and found the **OPA820**. The early attenuation above 270kHz (instead of the desired 300) is probably due to a reading error from me. I misunderstood the gray chart in the online tool. Where that vertical gray line is on the chart, it is not 300kHz. Anyway – it was just a matter of practice. Thanks to you all.

PS: There is no proper German word for *unity gain*. Well ... Whatever..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this in the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4022.pdf), front page: -

[image]

These devices are not suitable connected as unity gain amplifiers.